How Can I Add Separate ImageBackgrounds To Different Stack Screens in React Navigation?
I'm currently creating an app and would like to have different image backgrounds on each page.
All of the documentation I've found so far has only shown how to wrap the entire Navigation Container in one ImageBackground, how to add an Imagebackground to the Stack Screen header, or how to add only an image to a Stack Screen

Have you tried to add in an individual screen? There is nothing special about it. See https://reactnative.dev/docs/imagebackground.
